# Programming local APIC timer to issue interrupt

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, x86-64, interrupt

In one of my projects, I need a timer interrupt that should come on a specific core, and the handler should be executed on that core.

As there is a `local APIC timer` on each core, does the Linux kernel provide any interface to kernel space so I can program the timer to issue an interrupt?

Comment: If this is not a "general" question, you might want to tag with [x86], [arm] or whatever CPU you are working on.

Comment: You may look into the IRQ framework code that is responsible for the *interrupt replay*. Actually, what you are asking is interrupt affinity. You may attach the device's interrupt to any subset of CPU's.

Comment: @Oandriy No, I am not asking about interrupt affinity. Instead, I want to set a specified frequency to an `lapic timer` of a particular core and to write an interrupt handler to service whenever the timer interrupt arrives.